# Cannot save Clash of Clans progress

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a Sony Xperia Z1 on Android 4.4 KitKat and a Google Play Service, but when I want to save my account, it's not possible. Why?

I even made a second Google Play account to save my progress on Clash of Clans, but nothing happens: loading ring just rotate for a while and then nothing. Please help me, I don't want to lose my progress.

I tried to make more than one account, but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have an  Internet connection when loading clash of clans?

Comment: yes , Tamoghna Chowdhury 2  i have a good connection but i dont know why that happens

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are you using a modded version of clash of clans? Then Google play games isn't supposed to work.

Comment: am using the newest version , should i UNunistal  play games and then unistal it again???

Comment: You cannot do that. Play games is a system app.

Comment: oh yes i forgot ,,,but am afraid of losing my progress in the game ):

Comment: Did you download **Clash Of Clans** from **Google Play**? If not then it can fail because of a licence check. (Reply with @username please)

Comment: @Numbermaniac, my comment is specific for the OP. I am well aware that in some phones Google Play Games is not a system app